# Distances among grid coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


with tf.device("cpu:0"):
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    nRows = 10
    nCols = 15
    nNodes = nRows * nCols
    inputDim = 1

    rowIdxs = np.zeros([nRows, nCols])
    colIdxs = np.zeros([nRows, nCols])
    for rowIdx in range(nRows):
        for colIdx in range(nCols):
            rowIdxs[rowIdx, colIdx] = rowIdx
            colIdxs[rowIdx, colIdx] = colIdx

    rowIdxs = np.reshape(rowIdxs, [-1])
    colIdxs = np.reshape(colIdxs, [-1])

    distances = np.zeros([nNodes, nNodes])
    for i in range(nNodes):
        for j in range(nNodes):
            distances[i, j] = ((rowIdxs[i] - rowIdxs[j]) ** 2 + (colIdxs[i] - colIdxs[j]) ** 2)

    print('nRows', nRows, 'nCols', nCols, 'nNodes', nNodes)
    print('distances= ', distances.shape)
    print(distances)
```

TensorFlow is not used, I have left the import and the session for convenience.

Basically, this code computes a matrix `D(i, j)` where the element at `(i, j)` contains the Euclidean distance between the nodes `i` and `i` in linearized arrays of coordinates.

Even with small values of `nRows` and `nCols`, such as, for example, `100` and `100` this code is very slow. Thanks to the simmetry, I could compute only a triangular matrix, but the question would still be valid.

This a translation in python of a C++ code I wrote years ago. Since I have very little experience with both TensorFlow and Python, I would like to ask an advice on how to speed up a computation as simple as this one. Does TensorFlow offer any API for computing this cached matrix? I searched the docs but could not find any.

Comment: Did you try Scipy's cdist/pdist?

Comment: No, thank you, I'll check it out.